# Internet Explorer 11 does not respond to FSCommand

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, fscommand

In the Internet Explorer 11 the FSCommands seem unresponsive and no event is fired. Every other major browser seems to work fine.

A callback is registered to "domId_DoFSCommand". I also tried the addEventListener, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is not a big supporter of Flash:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/help/adobe-flash-not-working
I would highly recommend using a more advanced explorer such as Google Chrome. My best wishes to whatever project your working on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try to enable FScommand via meta tags

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all check if parameter AllowScriptAccess="always".
2. Try to turn on compatibility mode. If it works add meta teg to your web-site.

And better use ExternalInterface if it's possible.